# Entity Framework returning partially empty dataset

Tags: c#, iis-7, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5, asp.net-web-api

I have a dbcontext that I query to return a model that contains a total count of all the items and an Ienumerable type that represents a subset of the items. I have three environments: localhost, Development, and Test.  Using the same version of code, Development and localhost return the complete dataset with count and the list of items.  Test returns the proper count with an empty list of items.  The codeset is the same between all environments.  I have pointed all environments at the same database to isolate any issues that might exist in the DB.  The query looks like:

```
var rawItems = context.entity.Where(x => x.id == ID).OrderBy(x => x.id);
totalCount = rawItems.Count();
return rawItems.Skip(0).Take(25).Select(x => x.ToExternalModel())
```

ToExternalModel is a transformation method that takes the object and transforms it to a different model.  There are no exceptions thrown by this code.  I removed all try/catches to make sure.

I really think this is an environment problem I really don't know what else it could possibly be.

Comment: why do you need Skip(0)? If you just return the rawItems without converting it to the External Model, are the results same?

Comment: This piece of code represents the parameters I'm using to execute with.  In the real code, 0 is a variable and may not be 0.  I haven't tried just returning the list of raw items but for that to work would imply that the transformation is behaving differently on one out of 3 machines.

Comment: It turns out that the query generated on the Test server is different (different join structure) than the query generated on the other servers.  I am still researching why it might be different.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a bad foreign key definition in the Entity Framework Schema.  I'm still not sure why some environments created a working version of the query and one environment created a non working query.  I'm going to continue researching but fixing the foreign key definition was the solution.